# Java - Is binary code the same as ByteCode?

Tags: java, binary, jvm, bytecode

In Java, does "binary code" means the same as "Java bytecode?"

Is this the flow in Java ?

> Java File (.java) -> [javac] ->
>   ByteCode File (.class) -> [JVM/Java
>   Interpreter] -> Running it(by first
>   converting it into binary code
>   specific to the machine)

Thanks!

Comment: In what context did you see the term "binary code?"

Comment: I read somewhere java code is first converted to machine independent bytecode, while some said, it is converted to binary code. 
So I am a bit confused.

Comment: **Everything** is "binary code"!!! Oh noes!!

Comment: @Mandar: edited your question: I replaced *"javac.exe"* with *"javac"* because on Linux, OS X and all the other Unices Java works on the Windowsy-idiosynchratic *".exe"* doesn't make much sense ;)

Comment: Note that on most Real World [TM] JVMs Java isn't "interpreted" in the same way real interpreted languages are interpreted.  For a start (and that's a given on *any* JVM) it's, as you noted, not the source code but the bytecode that is "interpreted" (this alone makes already for a very weird definition of "interpreted" because it's amazingly more efficient than source-code interpretation) then most Real World [TM] JVMs are "JIT". JIT means compilation. This makes for an even weirder definition/usage of "interpreted".

Comment: So while it is not entirely false to say that Java is interpreted it is **highly misleading** (and typically done by people resorting to all kind of other logical fallacies to try to undermine Java).  Once again, most Real World [TM] JVMs, running Real World [TM] programs, do JIT.  And JIT means compilation.  And to me it rings a huge "logical-fallacy-troll-trying-to-undermine-Java-troll" sign when I read someone saying that Java is really an interpreted language. Benchmarks on the great language shootout agree with me on that one when it comes to comparing interpreted-vs-compiled languages ;)

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: It's not misleading at all: http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Intro.doc2.html - read 1.2.5. The fact that the JVM does some very clever JIT gymnastics to spit out performance that can compete with C and C++ doesn't mean the bytecode isn't interpreted, because it is. When Java does JIT, it also needs to warm up (and usually does several interpretation cycles before it switches over to JIT -- usually in performance-critical code blocks).

Comment: @David Titarenco: I never said it wasn't "interpreted".  I said referring to it as an interpreted language is highly misleading because it misleads people into thinking *a)* it's the source code that is interpreted and *b)* there's no JIT involved.  And the JIT "gymnastic" is pretty much a central piece of any Real World [TM] Java VM nowadays.  Your comment shows **precisely** what is wrong with calling Java an interpreted language.  Btw, there are also native Java CPU like the ones from Ajile systems where bytecode is natively executed....

Comment: @David Titarenco: The very fact that there are CPUs that can run native Java bytecode shows how close to the metal the Java bytecode is. Calling Java an interpreted language because it's bytecode, which has a one-to-one mapping for many of its instruction to machine code on many architecture, is interpreted **IS** highly misleading. I know that the Sun gods named it so but I think it's really sad they decided to go with that silly name, giving Java such a bad rep and countless, pointless, uninformed "Java is interpreted"* comments. Code that matters is JITed and is **NOT** interpreted anymore.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: But even code that is JITed is interpreted before it's JITed (until the JIT kicks in). I'm not arguing how close or far Java is from the metal, I just think it's important to understand the underlying principles of language design which this question addressed - the very principles which make Java and C++ (for example) very different languages from a theoretical standpoint. I do agree, though, that the blanket statement "Java is an interpreted language" can be a misnomer.

Comment: @David Titarenco, @SyntaxT3rr0r: guys, you talk about JVM like it is "real" program, and has only one implementation... There are different commercial and free JVMs, and they work different... "**JRockit does not include an interpreter**; so the JIT compilation of the byte code into native machine code has to occur before a method executes" - no interpretation, no warm up, just JIT :) [Understanding JIT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm). Please, when you argue, tell us which implementation you mean (HotSpot, JRockit, J9)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by **`binary code`**.

***`Java bytecode`*** is a binary data format that includes loading information and execution instructions for the Java virtual machine.  In that sense, ***`Java bytecode`*** is a special kind of **binary code**.

When you use the term "**binary code**" to mean machine instructions for a real processors architecture (like IA-32 or Sparc) then it is different.
***`Java bytecode`*** is not a **binary code** in that sense.  It is not processor-specific.

Answer (score 14):

JVM is very complex program, and the flow there is in certain level unpredictable. E.g. flow inside HotSpot JVM is something like the following:

1) it takes your bytecode and interprets it
2) if some method is executed quite frequently (some amount of times during some time span) it is marked as a "hot" method and JVM schedules its compiling to platform depended machine code (is that what you have called binary code?). That flow looks like the following:

```
ByteCode
--> Hige-level Intermediate Representation (HIR)
  --> Middle-level Intermediate Representation (MIR)
    --> Low-level Intermediate Representation (LIR)
      --> Register Allocation
        --> EMIT (platform dependent machine code)
```

Each step in that flow is important and helps JVM perform some optimizations of your code. It does not change your algorithm of course, optimization just means that some sequences of code can be detected and exchanged with better performing code (producing the same result). Starting from LIR stage, code becomes platform dependent (!).

Bytecode can be good for interpretation, but not good enough to be easily transformed into the machine native code. HIR takes care of it and its purpose is to quickly transform bytecode into an intermediate representation. MIR transforms all operations into the three-operands operation; ByteCode is based on stack operation:

```
iload_0
iload_1
iand
```

that was bytecode for simple `and` operation, and middle level representation for this will be sort of the following:

```
and v0 v1 -> v2
```

LIR depends on platform, taking into account our simple example with `and` operation, and specifying our platform as x86, then our code snippet will be:

```
x86_and v1 v0 -> v1
x86_move v1 -> v2
```

because `and` operation takes two operands, first one is destination, another one is source, and then we put the result value to another "variable". Next stage is "register allocation", because x86 platform (and probably most others) work with registers, and not variables (like intermediate representation), nor stack (like bytecode). Here our code snippet should be like the following:

```
x86_and eax ecx -> eax
```

and here you can notice absence of a "move" operation. Our code contained only one line and JVM figured out that creating a new virtual variable was not neede; we can just reuse the `eax` register. If code is big enough, having many variables and working with them intensive (e.g. using eax somewhere below, so we can't change its value), then you will see move operation left in machine code. That's again about optimization :)

That was JIT flow, but depending on VM implementation there can be one more step - if code was compiled (being "hot"), and still executed many many times, JVM schedules optimization of that code (e.g. using inlining).

Well, conclusion is that the path from bytecode to machine code is quite interesting, a bit unforeseeable, and depends on many many things.

btw, the described above process is called "Mixed mode interpretation" (when JVM first interprets bytecode, and then uses JIT compilation), example of such JVM is HotSpot. Some JVMs (like JRockit from Oracle) use JIT compilation only.

This was a very simple description of what is going on there. I hope that it helps to understand the flow inside JVM on a very high level, as well as targets the question about differences between bytecode and binary code. For references, and other issues not mentioned here and related to that topic, please read the similar topic "[Why are compiled Java class files smaller than C compiled files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838221/why-are-compiled-java-class-files-smaller-than-c-compiled-files/4838449#4838449)".

Also feel free to critique this answer, point me to mistakes or misunderstanding of mine, I'm always willing to improve my knowledge about JVM :)

Comment: @magnetar: thank you, glad to here it wasn't wasting of time ;)

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as "machine-independent-bytecode" (it wouldn't make any sense if you think about it). Bytecode is only (for the purposes of this answer) used for things like virtual machines. VMs (such as the JVM) **INTERPRET** the bytecode and use some clever and complicated just-in-time compilation (which **IS** machine/platform-dependent) to give you the final product.

So in a sense, both of the answers are right and wrong. The Java compiler compiles code into Java bytecode (machine-independent). The `*.class` files the bytecode is located in are binary - they are executable, after all. The Virtual machine later interprets these binary `*.class` files (note: when describing files as binary, it's somewhat of a misnomer) and does various awesome stuff. More often than not, the JVM uses something called JIT (just-in-time compilation), which generates either platform-specific, or machine-specific instructions that speed up various parts of execution. JIT is another topic for another day, however.

**Edit**:

```
Java File (.java) -> [javac.exe] -> ByteCode File (.class) -> [JVM/Java Interpreter] -> Running it(by first converting it into binary code specific to the machine)
```

This is incorrect. The JVM doesn't "convert" anything. It simply interprets the bytecode. The  only part of the JVM that "converts" bytecode is when the JIT compiler is invoked, which is a special case and should not be generalized.

Comment: You just said," JIT compilation" is machine independent. But I have read that JVM is specific for every machine, unlike a ByteCode.

Comment: JIT compilation is a small part of how the JVM works (and the ONLY part that "re-writes" code for a particular machine/platform). The VM is a platform/machine specific interpreter, but the bytecode is NOT.

Comment: Titerenco: Maybe I didn't get your "just-in-time compilation (which IS machine/platform-independent)", but JIT compilation is platform dependent, starting from LIR stage in flow it produces platform dependent code! The result of compilation is native platform dependent machine code, so it just can't be independent... bytecode is of cource platform independent...

Comment: @maxym: that's a typo, sorry. JIT IS platform-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Both C/C++ (to take as an example) and Java programs are compiled into ***Binary Code***. This generic term just means that the new created file does not encode the instructions in a human-readable way. (i.e. You won't be able to open the compiled file in a text program and read it).

On the other hand, what the Binary 0's and 1's encode (or represent), depends on what the compiler generated. In the case of Java, it generates instructions called ***Bytecode***, which are interpreted by the JVM. In other cases, for other languages, it may generate IA-32 or SPARC instructions.

In conclusion, the way the terms ***Binary code*** and ***Java bytecode*** are opposed to each other is misleading. The reason was to make the distinction between the normal binary code which is machine dependant, and the Java bytecode (also a binary code) which is not.

Answer (score 1):

Answer i found today for above question:

Source: [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1)

Loading refers to the process of finding the binary form of a class or interface type with a particular name, perhaps by computing it on the fly, but more typically by retrieving a binary representation previously computed from source code by a Java compiler, and constructing, from that binary form, a Class object to represent the class or interface.

The precise semantics of loading are given in Chapter 5 of The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition. Here we present an overview of the process from the viewpoint of the Java programming language.

**The binary format of a class or interface** is normally the class file format described in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition cited above, but other formats are possible, provided they meet the requirements specified in §13.1. The method defineClass of class ClassLoader may be used to construct Class objects from binary representations in the class file format.

Answer (score 0):

When the talk is going about programs then term **binary code** usually denote executable program in binary form (encoded as a sequence of bits).
In other words **binary code** is any **compiled program** as opposed to **scripts** which are distributed and executed (interpreted) in the form of text.

**Binary code** can be of two kinds: machine code and bytecode. **Machine code** is a program encoded in accordance to specification of real hardware microprocessor. Thus, it can be executed directly by target microprocessor without mediation of any other software. In contrast, **bytecode** is a program encoded in accordance to specification of some virtual microprocessor (virtual machine). Hence, for execution it can be either interpreted or translated into machine code and then directly executed.

In this way, every **bytecode** is a **binary code**, but not every **binary code** is **bytecode**. In the context of your question, "Java bytecode" is unconditionally a "binary code", but "binary code" will not necessary be "Java bytecode", but can be "Java bytecode".