# What is the difference between Binary Instrumentation and ByteCode instrumentation?

Tags: binary, bytecode, instrumentation

So I was reading this paper called "A Survey of Dynamic Program Analysis Techniques and Tools" and there's a listing of the different instrumentation techniques.

So according to that paper, we have source code, binary and byte-code instrumentation. The source code one is really clear, but I can't see the difference between byte-code and binary instrumentation:

> "Binary instrumentation adds instrumentation code by modifying or
>   re-writing compiled code"

and:

> Bytecode instrumentation performs tracing within the compiled code. [...]
>   Static [bytecode] instrumentation involves changing the compiled code
>   offline before execution

There's this post: [What are the differences between the three methods of code coverage analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255798/what-are-the-differences-between-the-three-methods-of-code-coverage-analysis)
speaking about "on-the-fly" instrumentation, which is really close to the "dynamic byte-code instrumentation" and "dynamic binary instrumentation".

> Dynamic binary instrumentation (implemented as Just-In-Time compilers) is performed after the program has been loaded into memory

and

> Dynamic [byte-code] instrumentation works when the application is already running

If anyone could explain me this difference between binary and byte-code instrumentation, that would be great.

Thank you very much.

Thibault

Answer (score 1):

IMHO...

> "Binary instrumentation adds instrumentation code by modifying or re-writing compiled code"

Compile code *is made of byte code*, so that is the same thing from what I see. Binary instrumentation probably just means that *binaries* are instrumented.

Comment: Oh, indeed, until now I thought that byte-code and binaries were the same thing. from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841083/java-is-binary-code-the-same-as-bytecode

Java bytecode is a binary data format that includes loading information and execution instructions for the Java virtual machine. In that sense, Java bytecode is a special kind of binary code.

When you use the term "binary code" to mean machine instructions for a real processors architecture (like IA-32 or Sparc) then it is different.
Java bytecode is not a binary code in that sense. It is not processor-specific.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I get it now.