# Why is an empty C program compiling to 47902 bytes?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a C/C++ “Hello World” in the kilobytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815005/why-is-a-c-c-hello-world-in-the-kilobytes)

Consider the following program written in ANSI C.

```
file: test.c
main() {}
```

I'm on Windows 7. I use MinGW to compile this file.

```
$ gcc test.c
```

Then, I want to see the size of this file.

```
$ ls -la a.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Username Administrators 47902 Nov 21 15:57 a.exe
```

It appears that this completely empty, worthless C program compiles to a binary that is *almost fifty kilobytes in size*. Why in the world is this happening?

Comment: You're statically linking the C standard library.  If you link to it dynamically, your exe size will be tiny

Comment: Unrelated, your programme is invalid. In C89, you need a `return 0;` (or whatever you want to return), in C99 and later, `main` needs an explicit return type.

Comment: It's not Windows, but you might like to read [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).

Comment: @DanielFischer, it's not invalid if it compiles.

Comment: Have you stripped the symbols? Pass the options `-s` as well.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson It's invalid if the standard says so. But compilers are not obliged to reject invalid programmes.

Comment: holy cow, @KerrekSB, that cut it down by 40,000 bytes.

Comment: “it's not invalid if it compiles” Sometimes it compiles and then it mysteriously stops working. Sometimes it compiles and then it only works in the debugger. See what I mean?

Comment: @PascalCuoq, in those cases usually tools like `valgrind` will tell you where the problem is :-).

Comment: @Isemi I was referring to previous questions by the author of the comment. I rely on static analysis for most of the undefined behaviors I am tracking down :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run GCC like `gcc -v test.c`. The GCC (the compiler driver) spawns `cc1` (the compiler), `as` (the assembler) and `ld` (the linker). Look at the linker command line and you'll see several files (something like `crti.o`, `crt0.o`, `crtbegin.o`, `crtend.o`, etc.) linked in the final executable. ANd some of them may fetch symbols from `libgcc.a` or `libc.a`. That explains why the size is not just a few bytes.

You could also run it with `-Wl,-Map=map.txt` to generate a map file, which will reveal every function or variable from every object and library, which is included in the final executable.