# Why is the executable(.exe file) file has a size greater than the compiled .C file?

Tags: c, size

Just out of curiosity, i wanted to know why are my compiled `.C` files(approx 2-5 kb) are smaller in size than my executable(.exe) files(130-200 kb)?

Comment: External libraries that aren't shared and such, and each line in the .c file gets turned into assembly, which could have more than one line for every C file, and then this gets turned into a binary file.  In other words, your text (printing hello world for instance), creates a lot of other stuff that is going on behind.

Comment: If you look at the code generated by compiler and try to match the corresponding C code in your source file, you'll understand why.

Comment: That is the reason that C is called a high level programming language.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but here's a great [blog post](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) that shows what it takes to make executables as small as possible on Linux. A quick Google search also revealed a [similar post](http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/) for Windows executables. (I haven't read the second one.)

Comment: @devnull I'm so glad I'm not alone with my opinion that C is a high-level language!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a C/C++ "Hello World" in the kilobytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815005/why-is-a-c-c-hello-world-in-the-kilobytes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You compiler source file is just the generated code from the actual source file and not much else. An executable have been linked with other object files and libraries, needed for all external functions and variables you need. That of course makes the executable much bigger as it contains much more code.

Answer (score 3):

Could be many reasons:

- The compiler may *statically link* dependent libraries, which essentially copies that machine code into the resulting executable
- Assembly often takes up more space that source code - a single line of code could be compiled to several lines of Assembly (moving data in/out of registers, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/207507)

> DJGPP programs need to bundle all sorts of pmode drivers for the
>   things that are typically done via the BIOS in rmode. THings like
>   memory management, disk access, console access, hardware access, etc.
>   In essence, DJGPP embeds a mini-OS inside your executable!